# Send messages to specific devices using new firebase API

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am writing a new server application (using .net) to send notifications to clients (mainly android devices), and I am using the new Http v1 api from firebase cloud messaging, I saw the following Post request body to send a notification for topics

```
{
  "message": {
    "topic": "news",
    "notification": {
      "title": "Breaking News",
      "body": "New news story available."
    },
    "data": {
      "story_id": "story_12345"
    }
  }
}
```

However how am I going to send a notification to specific device using FCM Id ?

Note: I had already implemented sending notification to single device using the legacy API.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is documentation for the v1 HTTP API.  Specifically, there is a section for [sending messages to a specific device](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_messages_to_specific_devices).  You need to know the device token:

```
{
  "message":{
    "token" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification": {
      "title": "Breaking News",
      "body": "New news story available."
    },
    "data": {
      "story_id": "story_12345"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, save my day :)