# How to send a push notification to one device?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm facing a problem that I don't know how to send a notification to any one device. For example, there is a task: The client has made a purchase and I ONLY need to show him a notification that the purchase has been made.

Here are some details that may be important (Please write if they are really important) -

1. We use webview.
2. Our WordPress site (please don't scold us)
3. All the current code (which is related to push notifications) that I currently have is located in the main.dart file

Next, I have a few questions. Am I getting a token when the app is initialized? Or do I need to receive it at another moment? At what point do I need to send a token to the server of our site? What code do I need to add so that the user can receive a notification that is intended specifically for him?

At the moment, all my code that is currently in main.dart is -

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  print("Обработка фонового сообщения : ${message.messageId}");
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  
  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
    alert: true,
    announcement: false,
    badge: true,
    carPlay: false,
    criticalAlert: false,
    provisional: false,
    sound: true,
  );

  String? token = await messaging.getToken();

if (kDebugMode) {
  print('Registration Token=$token');
}

  if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
    print('Пользователь предоставил разрешение');
  } else if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.provisional) {
    print('Пользователь предоставил временное разрешение');
  } else {
    print('Пользователь отклонил или не принял разрешение');
  }

  
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    print('Получил сообщение, находясь на переднем плане!');
    print('Данные сообщения: ${message.data}');

    if (message.notification != null) {
      print('Сообщение также содержало уведомление: ${message.notification}');
    }
  });

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return 
    
       MaterialApp(
   CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilderCustomBackGestureWidth(),
    
        home: SplashScreen());
   
    
  }
}
```

PS: In other places I have nothing that would be related to fairbase

Please let me know in the comments if you need any additional information.
PSS - this is my first time trying to send a notification to a specific user, so I don't understand anything at all

Comment: To send a message to one specific device, you specify the device token in the call to the FCM API. See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53554355/send-messages-to-specific-devices-using-new-firebase-api

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm sorry, but unfortunately I can't consider the link with the answer as a solution, because it does not give a specific answer to any of my questions